# Java Graphics not showing on Mac even with overriding the paintComponent() method of the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm working on a small game project and am having an issue with java graphics not being displayed. I've searched similar questions here on Stackoverflow and used overriding the paintComponent() method of the JPanel which many ppl advised but am still having this issue. I hope to get my background image and menubar, and music at the same time. Music works fine but background image and menubar doesn't show up at all.

here's my code :

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DynamicBeat extends JFrame {

    private Image screenImage;
    private Graphics screenGraphic;

    private Image introBackground = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/introBackground(Title).jpg")).getImage();
    private JLabel menuBar = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/menuBar.png")));

    public DynamicBeat() {

        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 30);
        add(menuBar);

        Music introMusic = new Music("introMusic.mp3", true);
        introMusic.start();

        setUndecorated(true);
        setTitle("Dynamic Beat Game");
        setSize(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setLayout(null);
        add(new DynamicBeatPane());
        pack();

    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        screenImage = createImage(Main.SCREEN_WIDTH, Main.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        screenGraphic = screenImage.getGraphics();
        screenDraw(screenGraphic);
        g.drawImage(screenImage, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void screenDraw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(introBackground, 0, 0, null);
        this.repaint();
    }

    public static class DynamicBeatPane extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // Call the superclass paint method.
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The overridden `paint` method of the `JFrame` looks very suspicious, especially in that it refers to a cached `Graphics` object. What is the intended purpose of that override?

Comment: BTW 1) Pet peeve of mine. Both `JFrame` and `JPanel` implement `ImageObserver` so calls like `g.drawImage(.., 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(.., 0, 0, this);` 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: 1) Don't override paint(). 2) Don't use a null layout. Instead use the default `BorderLayout` of the frame for you "menuBar" and "DynamicBeatPanel". 3) To display a background image see: [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for two approaches.